# Emails sent but never received

Tags: asp.net, email

We have developed a web app using ASP.NET, .NET 3.5 and SQL Server 2008. It runs on IIS on a Windows Server 2008 R2 server. It has a feature by which, under some circumstances, the app sends email to the user's registered email address using classes in System.Net.Mail. It usually works fine: a few seconds after the email is sent by our application, the user has the email message in his/her inbox.

However, in some cases, the user never gets the email message. This happens in an apparent random fashion, and we haven't been able to detect any patterns. We have checked spam filters and folders, and made sure that the email addresses are OK. In one instance, we had two users from the same company, with addresses abc@company.co.uk and xyz@company.co.uk; one of them gets his emails perfectly, whereas the other never gets them.

Any idea of where to start debugging this? Thank you.

Comment: I think it will be better suited for Server Fault. It can be something to do with the exchange server also. right?

Comment: @Shoban: No Exchange server is involved. We are using an external SMTP server that our hosted email provider supplies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have worked with e-mail myself, and the first lesson I learned was to have a contact in the sysadmin group. They can actually see when a mail arrived, wether it was accepted or not, and wether it was send on successfully or not.

Probably not really relating to your problem, but interesting to read anyway, is [this story about e-mail sending on Coding Horror](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/04/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code.html), written by SO dev Jeff Atwood. It's always good to know a bit more on the problem domain :)

Answer (score 2):

Ask your local friendly server administrator to check the mailroot folder.  They might be stuck in the Queue folder, or they might be in the Badmail folder.  Also ask them to check the SMTP logs.

Be nice to them and provide them with specific email addresses and the approximate times the emails were sent =)